# "Conditional" parsing of command-line arguments

Tags: c++, command-line, terminal, command-line-arguments

Say I have an executable (running on mac, win, and linux)

```
 a.out [-a] [-b] [-r -i <file> -o <file> -t <double> -n <int> ]
```

where an argument in `[ ]` means that it is optional. However, if the last argument `-r` is set then `-i`,`-o`,`-t`, and `-n` have to be supplied, too.

There are lots of good C++-libraries out there to parse command-line arguments, e.g. gflags (http://code.google.com/p/gflags/), tclap (http://tclap.sourceforge.net/), simpleopt(http://code.jellycan.com/simpleopt/), boost.program_options (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options.html), etc. But I wondered if there is one that lets me encode these conditional relationships between arguments directly, w/o manually coding error handling

```
if ( argR.isSet() && ( ! argI.isSet() || ! argO.isSet() || ... ) ) ...
```

and manually setting up the `--help`.

The library [tclap](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/) allows to XOR arguments, e.g. either `-a` or `-b` is allowed but not both. So, in that terminology an AND for arguments would be nice.

*Does anybody know a versatile, light-weight, and cross-platform library that can do that?*

Comment: [Here](http://www.boost.org/libs/program_options/example/real.cpp) is the example from Boost.Program_options that deals with conflicting and dependent options.

Answer (score 2):

You could two passes over the arguments; If `-r` is in the options you reset the parser and start over with the new mandatory options added.

---

You could also look into how the TCLAP `XorHandler` works, and create your own `AndHandler`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but then you still have to code the help-screen yourself (which is not a problem, but would be nice to have). Adding the AndHandler would be a good option, I guess.

Comment: @Nick The help-screen needs special handling anyway. One thing I like about Boost program-options is that it doesn't show the help screen itself, but you have to provide your own `--help` option and check for that and print the help yourself. This way you can just add the special options and print it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the argument syntax so that -r takes four values in a row.

Comment: This would be rather confusing, though, as that's not how arguments generally work

Comment: True, however, they could be different data types. As far as I know, the libraries mentioned in the question handle multi-arguments (only) as one type.

Answer (score 0):

I have part of the `TCLAP` snippet of code lying around that seems to fit the error handling portion that you're looking for, however it doesn't match exactly what you're looking for:

```
# include "tclap/CmdLine.h"

namespace TCLAP {

class RequiredDependentArgException : public ArgException {
public:
  /**
   * Constructor.
   * \param text - The text of the exception.
   * \param parentArg - The text identifying the parent argument source
   * \param dependentArg - The text identifying the required dependent argument
   * of the exception.
   */
  RequiredDependentArgException(
    const TCLAP::Arg& parentArg,
    const TCLAP::Arg& requiredArg)
  : ArgException(
    std::string( "Required argument ") +
    requiredArg.toString() +
    std::string(" missing when the ") +
    parentArg.toString() +
    std::string(" flag is specified."),
    requiredArg.toString())
  { }
};

} // namespace TCLAP
```

And then make use of the new exception after `TCLAP::CmdLine::parse` has been called:

```
if (someArg.isSet() && !conditionallyRequiredArg.isSet()) {
  throw(TCLAP::RequiredDependentArgException(someArg, conditionallyRequiredArg));
}
```

I remember looking in to extending and adding an additional class that would handle this logic, but then I realized the only thing I was actually looking for was nice error reporting because the logic wasn't entirely straightforward and couldn't be easily condensed (at least, not in a way that was useful to the next poor guy who came along). A contrived scenario dissuaded me from pursuing it further, something to the effect of, "if A is true, B must be set but C can't be set if D is of value N." Expressing such things in native C++ is the way to go, especially when it comes time to do very strict argument checks at CLI arg parse time.

For truly pathological cases and requirements, create a state machine using something like [Boost.`MSM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html) (Multi-State Machine). HTH.

Answer (score -1):

do you want to parse a command line?you can use simpleopt,it can be used as followings:downLoad simpleopt from:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/simpleopt/downloads

test:
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR * argv[])
argv can be:1.txt 2.txt *.cpp